# Removing stopwords and tokenization in python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have following input data and I would like to remove stopwords from this input and want to do tokenization:

```
input = [['Hi i am going to college', 'We will meet next time possible'],
         ['My college name is jntu', 'I am into machine learning specialization'],
         ['Machine learnin is my favorite subject' ,'Here i am using python for 
              implementation']]
```

I have tried following code but not getting desired results:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 

word_tokens = word_tokenize(input) 

filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 

filtered_sentence = [] 

for w in word_tokens: 
    if w not in stop_words: 
        filtered_sentence.append(w) 

#print(word_tokens) 
print(filtered_sentence)
```

Expecting output like below:

```
Output = [['Hi', 'going', 'college', 'meet','next', 'time', 'possible'],
          ['college', 'name','jntu', 'machine', 'learning', 'specialization'],
          ['Machine', 'learnin', 'favorite', 'subject' ,'using', 'python', 'implementation']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will help you.

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
op=[]
for item in _input:
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(' '.join(item).lower()) 
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 
    op.append(filtered_sentence)
print(op)
```

Each item in your list has two strings. So, join them as a single string and remove the stopwords.

Answer (score 0):

Start like before

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 

input_ = [['Hi i am going to college', 'We will meet next time possible'],
         ['My college name is jntu', 'I am into machine learning specialization'],
         ['Machine learnin is my favorite subject' ,'Here i am using python for implementation']]
```

I think is is better to name your input `input_` since `input` already has a meaning in Python.

I would start with flattening your input. Instead of a nested list of lists, we should have a single lists of sentences:

```py
input_flatten = [sentence for sublist in input for sentence in sublist]
print(input_flatten)
>>>['Hi i am going to college',
 'We will meet next time possible',
 'My college name is jntu',
 'I am into machine learning specialization',
 'Machine learnin is my favorite subject',
 'Here i am using python for implementation']
```

Then you can go through every sentences and remove the stop words like so:

```py
sentences_without_stopwords = []
for sentence in input_flatten:
    sentence_tokenized = word_tokenize(sentence)
    stop_words_removed = [word for word in sentence_tokenized if word not in stop_words]
    sentences_without_stopwords.append(stop_words_removed)

print(sentences_without_stopwords)
>>>[['Hi', 'going', 'college'],
 ['We', 'meet', 'next', 'time', 'possible'],
 ['My', 'college', 'name', 'jntu'],
 ['I', 'machine', 'learning', 'specialization'],
 ['Machine', 'learnin', 'favorite', 'subject'],
 ['Here', 'using', 'python', 'implementation']]
```